# csrf_token missing and how to get details for specific id entered by user

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to display the result for the specific id entered by the user. I 'm not sure about the view.py file also. What changes should I need to make to get the desired result?

view.py file

```
def show(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        Num = allData.objects.only('emp_no')
        data = request.POST.get('emp_no')
        if data.is_valid():
            for n in Num:
                if n == data:
                    empid = data
                    emp = {'emp_no':data}
            return render(request,'system/show.html',{'emp_no':data})
        return(data.errors)    
    return HttpResponse("<h2>OOPS!! NO RECORD FOUND</h2>")
```

show.html

```
{% extends 'system/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block body_block %}

<div class="container" "jumbotron">
    <h2>Details</h2>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label class="lb" for="emp_no" >Employee No.</label>
        <input type="number" name="emp_no">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">SUBMIT</button>
    </form>
            {% for allData in emp_no %}

                {{ allData.GENDER_CHOICE}}
                {{ allData.first_name }}
                {{ allData.last_name }}
                {{ allData.birth_day }}
                {{ allData.hire_date }}
                {{ allData.dept_no }}
                {{ allData.dept_name }}
                {{ allData.salary }}
                {{ allData.from_date }}
                {{ allData.to_date }}
                {{ allData.titles }}

            {% endfor %}    

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

From what you have there it looks like it would be worthwhile taking a look at the [Django forms documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/).

The main thing that jumps out to me is that you are trying to reuse the same template both for the form and for the data display after the form is submitted. It might be easier to separate them.

If you do want to keep one template, then you don't want to show the form if there is data and vice versa - if there is no data, then you want to show the form. It would look something like this:

```
{% if emp_no %}
    {% for allData in emp_no %}

        {{ allData.GENDER_CHOICE}}
        {{ allData.first_name }}
        {{ allData.last_name }}
        {{ allData.birth_day }}
        {{ allData.hire_date }}
        {{ allData.dept_no }}
        {{ allData.dept_name }}
        {{ allData.salary }}
        {{ allData.from_date }}
        {{ allData.to_date }}
        {{ allData.titles }}

    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       {% csrf_token %}
       <label class="lb" for="emp_no" >Employee No.</label>
       <input type="number" name="emp_no">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">SUBMIT</button>
    </form>
{% endif %}
```

The title of your question also mentions csrf_token problems. You didn't give any details, but my guess is things are getting confused because you are loading the form even when you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

I will point out a few things before trying to post a solution.

1. Your code is not that readable because of the way you name variables. Try naming your variables in a way that tries to reflect what your code is doing.
2. I will suggest that you finish [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/) if you haven't done that already. It will help you grab the core concepts of Django.

From what I understood you are trying to get an employee with a given employee number.
This is how I would  do it.

In the views.py I would user `render` instead of `HttpResponse`.

```
def show(request):

    context = {}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # extract the emp no from the request
        emp_no = request.POST.get('emp_no')

        # get or create the employee with this emp_no
        current_employee = Employee.objects.get_or_create(emp_no)

        context['current_employee'] = current_employee

    return render(request, 'show.html', context)
```

In the templates, you don't need a forloop. You are retrieving only one employee.

```
{% extends 'system/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block body_block %}

<div class="container" "jumbotron">
    <h2>Details</h2>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label class="lb" for="emp_no" >Employee No.</label>
        <input type="number" name="emp_no">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">SUBMIT</button>
    </form>

    <div>
        {{ current_employee.GENDER_CHOICE}}
        {{ current_employee.first_name }}
        {{ current_employee.last_name }}
        {{ current_employee.birth_day }}
        {{ current_employee.hire_date }}
        {{ current_employee.dept_no }}
        {{ current_employee.dept_name }}
        {{ current_employee.salary }}
        {{ current_employee.from_date }}
        {{ current_employee.to_date }}
        {{ current_employee.titles }}
    </div>


</div>

{% endblock %}
```